# Cannot access the element using the "Contains" keyword (Selenium,Python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to access the following element using the contains keyword but I fail every time:

```
<div class="country_item " data-region="4">
<label class="chk-label-active" for="country_255">Bulgaria</label>
<div class="jcf-class-save-checkbox chk-area chk-checked">
<span/>
</div>
<input id="country_255" class="save-checkbox jcf-hidden" data-allowlist="378,438,183" name="jform[country][]" value="255" data-currency="2" data-bond_count="19" checked="checked" type="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
1. //*[contains(text(), 'Bulgaria')])
2. //*[@id='country']/div[15][@label='Bulgaria']
```

(it's a list of countries and Bulgaria is under div[15]

Can anyone help me to find out what the problem is?

Comment: Post the complete url o complete HTML, maybe you have to switch to a frame

Comment: The xpath, you have written seems good for me. I doubt like, 1) Is this elements are inside any frame? 2) Is this element is visible in the screen or did we need to scroll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 //*[contains(text(), 'Bulgaria')])
```

To break this down,

- `*` is a selector that matches any element (i.e. tag) -- it returns a node-set.
- The `[]` are a conditional that operates on each individual node in that node set. It matches if any of the individual nodes it operates on match the conditions inside the brackets.
- `text()` is a selector that matches all of the text nodes that are children of the context node -- it returns a node set.
- `contains` is a function that operates on a string. If it is passed a node set, the node set is converted into a string by returning the string-value of the node in the node-set that is first in document order. Hence, it can match only the first text node in your  element -- namely BLAH BLAH BLAH. Since that doesn't match, you don't get a  in your results.

**You need to change this to**

```
 //*[text()[contains(.,'Bulgaria')]]
```

- `*` is a selector that matches any element (i.e. tag) -- it returns a node-set.
- The outer `[]` are a conditional that operates on each individual node in that node set -- here it operates on each element in the document.
- `text()` is a selector that matches all of the text nodes that are children of the context node -- it returns a node set.
- The inner `[]` are a conditional that operates on each node in that node set -- here each individual text node. Each individual text node is the starting point for any path in the brackets, and can also be referred to explicitly as . within the brackets. It matches if any of the individual nodes it operates on match the conditions inside the brackets.
- `contains` is a function that operates on a string. Here it is passed an individual text node `(.)`. Since it is passed the second text node in the `<Comment>` tag individually, it will see the `'Bulgaria'` string and be able to match it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! It was very helpful . When I tried://[text()[contains(.,'Bulgaria')]] I got InvalidSelectorException exception

Answer (score 0):

**You can try following Xpath options:**

```
//label[contains(.,'Bulgaria')]
//label[contains(text(),'Bulgaria')]
//div[contains(@class,'country_item')]/label[contains(.,'Bulgaria')]
```